# Radicals: がしら (gashira) endings?

Tags: meaning, kanji, radicals

Does somebody know for what the [がしら]{gashira} ending stands in radicals like:

- eight (はちがしら{hachigashira})
- winter (ふゆがしら{fuyugashira}), or
- short thread (いとがしら{itogashira})?

Is it part of あし{ashi} (bottom radical position) or ashi variant (center radical position / top and bottom radical position)? I understand the other endings (kanmuri, gamae-kamae, hen-ben, nyō, tare, etc.).

I know some of them don't have those endings and could be phonetic (sound) parts of kanji and not semantic (meaning).

Comment: Do you understand http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A0%AD_(%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[かしら]{頭} (the 漢字 is also read あたま) means "head" and ふゆがしら etc. refer to the top part of the component.